# Check if item in array is in variable PHP

Tags: php, html

I have the following code

```
$var = "cat";
$array = ["cat", "dog", "mouse"];
```

How would I check if any item from `$array` is in `$var`? Something like

```
if($array in $var) {
    task()
}
```

Comment: [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: you would do the opposite (check if `$var` is in the array). `if(in_array($var, $array))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in_array is the way to go!
Like this:

```
if(in_array($var, $array)){
    task();
}
```

`in_array($needle, $haystack)` searches your Array `$haystack` for your var `$needle`. returns true if your Array contains your var.

Comment: Will accept in 4m